# Erasing Alpha does not erase the Mesh in Texture Paint?

Tags: mesh, texturing, texture-painting

I started texture painting this object. I came across the brush tool "Erase Alpha". So i started removing some of the mesh (at least thats what i thought) in solid view.

[image]
[image]

But when i go into rendered mode, it doesn't actually erase any of the mesh, it just turns it black. I thought that if it really did erase the mesh, i could have got the "ripped" cloth look i was looking for without remodeling the mesh. I guess there is no way to actually erase the mesh as easy as that?

I know there are better ways to create cloth, but its a low poly mesh so yeh. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to build a material that shows transparency in thoose black spot areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In eevee you have to select the material and enable "Alpha something" as blend mode in the settings.

[image]

Comment: Is it ok to change it after applying texture paint already l? Or do I have to start over?

Comment: It's ok, it's just a material attribute, the alpha of your PNG has been already modified.